# How to customize Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition Gnome panel?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

In 10.10 Ubuntu Netbook edition the panel is even more locked down than in 10.04. Is it possible to unlock it so that one can add/remove things from it? Will the 10.04 method of unlocking work with 10.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu Network Edition has the Unity interface. This provides the dock on the side and the panel. The panel is not gnome-panel, but part of unity so you can't add panel applets to it. I think Unity is deliberately unconfigurable to improve usability (it is up to you whether or not you agree with this philosophy).

If you want a more configurable interface, you can switch to using a normal GNOME desktop. You can add a panel applet for the global menu to the GNOME panel and use a dock such as docky. This will give you a similar, but more configurable) interface. You will, however, lose out on some of unity's features such as the search interface.

Answer (score 2):

No, that method won't work, as the new UNE interface uses a specifically created panel, not in any form related to the old gnome-panel UNE in Lucid used. So, as of now, you really can't customize/add/remove things.

This new panel only holds down the indicator-applet (indicator-applet-complete) package. Let's see what's coming in Natty for UNE and if options like this one, autohide, etc, are added.

Answer (score 0):

to remove a program from the side panel: right click -> remove from launcher. 
to add a program to the side panel: open program, right click -> Keep in launcher.

Comment: To clarify the question was about customizing the top panel.